# How to detect matched route from a component outside of the <Route/> component that was matched using react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've got the following structure in my React app, using `react-router-dom`.

```
<Router>
  <Header/>
  <Main>
    <AllRoutes>      // THIS HANDLES THE SWITCH WITH ALL THE ROUTES
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={ROUTES.HOME} component={Home}/>
        <Route exact path={ROUTES.ABOUT} component={About}/>
        <Route exact path={ROUTES.PRIVACY} component={Privacy}/>
        // ETC
      </Switch>
    </AllRoutes>
  </Main>
  <Footer/>         // <==== FOOTER NEEDS TO KNOW WHICH ROUTE HAS BEEN MATCH
<Router>
```

**QUESTION**

Footer needs to know what `<Route/>` has been match. What is the best pattern to achieve that?

---

**OPTION #1**

I found the `useRouteMatch` hook over on [react router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch):

[image]

[image]

This would kind of work, but I don't think it is good enough for my situation. Because a URL string can match a route and still don't be a valid route at the same time.

For example:

- Route:                                 `/:language/privacy`
- Valid route:                           `/en/privacy`
- Not valid route that would also match: `/notALanguage/privacy`

Once a route has match, I usually need to check if it is valid before rendering a component page or the 404 page.

Like:

```
<Route exact path={"/:language/privacy"} render={(routeProps) => {
 const possibleLanguage = routeProps.match.params.language;
 if (possibleLanguage in LANGUAGES) {
   return(
     <PrivacyPage lang={possibleLanguage}/>
   );
 }
 else {
  return(
    <Page404/>
  );
 }
}}/>
```

**OPTION #2**

What I'm thinking about doing is:

- `App.js` calls `useLocation`. So it always re-render when there is a route change.
- I could add a `detectRoute` function in `App.js` to do all the route checking beforehand.
- And my `AllRoutes` component wouldn't need a  component. I would implement a native JS switch and render the corresponding route.
- This way I know upfront which `<Route/>` is going to match and I can pass it on to `<Footer/>` or any component that lives outside of the matched `<Route/>`.

Something like this:

[SandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-platform-274ng?file=/src/App.js)

```
export default function App() {
  console.log("Rendering App...");

  const location = useLocation();

  // THIS WOULD BE THE detectRoute FUNCTION
  // I COULD EVEN USE THE useRouteMatch HOOK IN HERE
  const matchedRoute =
    location.pathname === ROUTE1
      ? "ROUTE1"
      : location.pathname === ROUTE2
      ? "ROUTE2"
      : "404";

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="App">
        <Link to={ROUTE1}>Route 1</Link>
        <Link to={ROUTE2}>Route 2</Link>
        <Link to={"/whatever"}>Route 404</Link>
      </div>
      <div>
        <AllRoutes matchedRoute={matchedRoute} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function AllRoutes(props) {
  switch (props.matchedRoute) {
    case "ROUTE1":
      return <Route exact path={ROUTE1} component={Page1} />;
    case "ROUTE2":
      return <Route exact path={ROUTE2} component={Page2} />;
    default:
      return <Route exact path={"*"} component={Page404} />;
  }
}
```

It works. But I would like to know if there's a proper way of doing this, 'cause this seems a bit weird and there might be something out there that was specifically designed for this.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want to either:

1. Wrap the components together
2. Create another switch to route them (and pass match params)

I put together a somewhat comprehensive [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-voice-lk1bk?file=/src/App.js) of the options.  Hope that helps!

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Switch, Link, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const hoc = (Component, value) => () => (
  <>
    <main>
      <Component />
    </main>
    <Footer value={value} />
  </>
);

const Wrapper = ({ component: Component, value }) => (
  <>
    <main>
      <Component />
    </main>
    <Footer value={value} />
  </>
);

const WrapperRoute = ({ component, value, ...other }) => (
  <Route
    {...other}
    render={props => <Wrapper component={component} value={value} {...props} />}
  />
);

const Footer = ({ value }) => <footer>Footer! {value}</footer>;
const Header = () => <header>Header!</header>;

const Another = () => <Link to="/onemore">One More!</Link>;
const Home = () => <Link to="/other">Other!</Link>;
const OneMore = () => <Link to="/">Home!</Link>;
const Other = () => <Link to="/another">Another!</Link>;

export default () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
      {/* You could inline it! */}
      <Route
        path="/another"
        render={() => (
          <>
            <main>
              <Another />
            </main>
            <Footer value="" />
          </>
        )}
      />
      {/* You could use a custom route component (that uses an HOC or a wrapper) */}
      <WrapperRoute
        component={OneMore}
        path="/onemore"
        value="I got one more!"
      />
      {/* You could use a Higher-Order Component! */}
      <Route path="/other" component={hoc(Other, "I got other!")} />
      {/* You could use a wrapper component! */}
      <Route
        path="/"
        render={() => <Wrapper component={Home} value="I got home!" />}
      />
    </Switch>
    {/* You could have another switch for your footer (inline or within the component) */}
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/another"
        render={() => <Footer value="Switch footer another!" />}
      />
      <Route
        path="/other"
        render={() => <Footer value="Switch footer other!" />}
      />
      <Route
        path="/onemore"
        render={() => <Footer value="Switch footer onemore!" />}
      />
      <Route path="/" render={() => <Footer value="Switch footer home!" />} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Note the WrapperRoute would allow you to do validation on your match params before passing them through.  You could do a `Redirect` if needed.

Comment: Thanks, jack. Those are really good solutions. I think I might end up moving `<Footer/>` to inside the `<Routes/>`. I will use the render prop like `<Route .... render={(routeProps) => <React.Fragment><Componen1/><Footer/></React.Fragment>} />`I think that is the easiest way out of this.What you think? Similar to your `Wrapper` solution, but using the render prop from `<Route/>`.

Comment: It sounds like you are considering the inline example.  The only issue with that one is that for multiple routes you would need to duplicate the contents of the render method, or have a helper function that returns what you need.  You may want to consider the `WrapperRoute` example for centralizing your logic.  However, any of the examples will work, do what resonates with you!

Answer (score 1):

What I've ended up doing:

Since I'm using Redux, I added a piece of global state to keep track of the matched route.

And I dispatch actions to update that state from the `render` prop from the `<Route/>`'s component.

```
<Switch>
  <Route key={index} exact path={"/some-route"} render={(routeProps) => {

    // HERE I DISPATCH AN ACTION TO CHANGE THE STATE FOR THE CURRENT ROUTE

    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_CURRENT_ROUTE,
      payload: { name: "SOME_ROUTE_NAME" }
    });

    return (
      <PrivacyPage
        {...routeProps}
      />
    );

  }}/>
</Switch>
```

And now I can do on **Footer.js**:

```
function Footer() {

  const currentRoute = useSelector((state) => state.currentRoute);

  // RENDER FOOTER ACCORDINGLY TO THE CURRENT ROUTE
}
```